# Non-Image Based Deep Neural Networks

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am looking for resources to research on the topic of deep neural networks with respect to non-image classification (i.e. non-MNST). I have a large, tabular dataset and I would like to predict one of the columns using the rest as input to the network. I am very new to this and am struggling to find the right key words to google to get a relevant example. Does my problem make sense?

I am using tensorflow.

Comment: It is better to ask your question on other StackExchange websites like https://stats.stackexchange.com/ because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, MLPs and later DNNs are often used for classification/regression problems on generic numerical/categorical features.

Here is an example: [Classification using DecisionTree, DNN Classifier](https://www.kaggle.com/raghavbirla/classification-using-decisiontree-dnn-classifier)

Also, it is widely used for speech recognition: [Deep Neural Networks for Acoustic Modeling in Speech Recognition](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/ru//pubs/archive/38131.pdf)

I would only suggest to normalize your inputs, i.e. make the features to be in range [0, 1] or [-1, 1], otherwise you might have hard times to train it.

This question indeed fits better to http://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: that first link is gold! Thanks!